# dd command 'no such file or directory'

Tags: sd-card, dd

I am trying to put a .img file onto a sd card to later put onto a raspberry pi.
I run the following command `dd bs=4M if=~/Home/Downloads/kali.img of=/dev/sdb`
and the following result puts out `dd: failed to open "/Home/Downloads"/kali.img: No such file or directory` kali.img is the file I am trying to put onto the sd card. I am also running this command as root. But, I am still very new to Linux and would like all the help I can get, Thanks!

Comment: Whats the output of `test -f ~/Home/Downloads/kali.img && echo 'Found' || echo 'Not Found'`?

Comment: Your Downloads folder is either `$/Downloads/` or `/home/username/Downloads`.

Comment: Home -> home, use the lower case.

Comment: Because you are logged in as root, ~/ is not a path to your home directory. When you are logged in as root, ~/ is the same as / instead of /home/$USER/. This is why the output lists "/Home/Downloads" instead. You should be using sudo and should not be logged in as root. Using sudo will give your user root permission.

Comment: @JulianLai This is true but that won't work either as there should be a username directory between /home and /Downloads and the path listed has ~/ which is supposed to be a shortcut to /home/$USER/.

Comment: @mchid root user's home is `/root/` not `/`. It *was* `/` previously, but is now deprecated.

Comment: the test command ended up sending me an error saying "Not Found". The file is clearly in my downloads and I dont know what it says from there.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Okay, maybe you can explain why the error saying failed to open "/Home/Downloads"/kali.img instead of failed to open "/root/Home/Downloads"/kali.img

Comment: @mchid `/Home/Downloads` is the *absolute* path provided by the user. He did *not* do `sudo ~/...` - he did `sudo /Home/Downloads...`.

Comment: Ok, decaptialize the `home` and drop the `~` to make the path `/home/Downloads/kali.img`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you missed the file path, there should be `/home/username/Downloads` not `/Home`, please recheck your path with `ls -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the correct path to the file is `~/Downloads/kali.img` but you shouldn't run this command as root you should be using `sudo`.

[Click here for more information on sudo if you are not familiar with this command.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Commands)

Running the command as root will change the path of `~/` from `/home/$USER` to `/` which is why the error lists the path as `/Home/Downloads` instead of `/home/$USER/Home/Downloads` as it would if you had used sudo.

Now, **exit out of root and log in as a *non root user* that has `sudo` permission.**

Then, run the following command to locate the correct path to the file and then change your `dd` command to reflect the correct path.

```
find ~/ -name '*kali*img' 2>&1 | egrep '*kali*'
```

---

The correct command should look like this (again, **you should not be logged in as root!**):

```
sudo dd bs=4M if="/home/kushkiddo/Downloads/kali.img" of=/dev/sdb
```

or

```
sudo dd if="/home/kushkiddo/Downloads/kali.img" of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

---

To explain:

The commands listed on the kali linux website are those listed for a kali user and kali users are normally logged in as root.

For Ubuntu, it is assumed that the user will use the `sudo` command instead of logging in as `root` to perform functions that require root permission.

On Ubuntu, the root account is deleted and so the path of `~/` is the top level directory `/` instead of a user or root user directory such as `/home/$USER/` or `/root` like it would be if you were logged in as a regular user on Ubuntu or as root when using kali respectively.

Comment: I understand the sudo and root permissons now, Thank you. But it seems when I try each one of these commands it ends up doing this `usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V` and all of its various attributes and what they do. I dont understand these and how they could potentionally help me.

Comment: @Bobatehfett You need to type the entire line and *then* press enter. Please run the following command and please post the output, thanks!: `sudo find / -name '*kali*img' 2>&1 | egrep '*kali*'`

Comment: Here is the output '/home/kushkiddo/Downloads/kali.img' and kali is in red. I think I am getting closer to figuring this out!.

Comment: @Bobatehfett `sudo dd bs=4M if="/home/kushkiddo/Downloads/kali.img" of=/dev/sdb` This is a single line command; copy and paste the entire command into the terminal and then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is a shortcut to the current user's home folder. You can verify this by typing:

```
echo ~
```

Typically a users's home folder will be at `/home/THEIRUSERNAME`, but for root it is `/root`.

I'm guessing `kali.img` is saved at `/home/YOURUSERNAME/Downloads/Kali.img`, but presently you're telling DD it's at `/root/Home/Downloads/Kali.img`.

If `kali.img` is in your user's download folder, then the correct command would be:

```
dd if=/home/YOURUSERNAME/Downloads/kali.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

Substitute `YOURUSERNAME` for your username obviously.

Please, always verify paths before running a DD command, because if you accidentally overwrite something, you will not be able to recover it. It's the equivalent of zeroing it.

Comment: I tested my commands before posting, and "~" points to /root when running as root, which is what the OP is doing.

Comment: The command works, but now its saying `failed to open /dev/sdb/ : permisson denied`

Answer (score 0):

The following command `sudo dd bs=4M if="/home/YOURUSERNAME/Downloads/" of=/dev/sdb` is the answer.

The `/dev/sdb` is the place you are writing it to,

If you are struggling to find where the image is I found out that using this command `sudo find / -name '*FILE*img' 2>&1 | egrep '*FILENAME*`

I would like to thank mchid for your very detailed descriptions about each command, and what it does.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, decaptialize `Home` and drop the `~` to make the path `/home/Downloads/kali.img`.

Directory names are case sensitive and `~` expands to the home directory of the **current user** (in `root`'s case: `/root`).

Answer (score 0):

`dd` is a powerful but dangerous tool. It does what you tell it to do without questions, so it is easy to write to the wrong device and overwrite valuable data, for example the family pictures.

I suggest that you install **mkusb**, which wraps a safety belt around `dd`. **mkusb** can clone image files (and also image files compressed with `gzip` and `xz`) to a target drive (typically a USB pendrive or a memory card).

See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Expansion_and_imaging_from_a_compressed_image_file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Expansion_and_imaging_from_a_compressed_image_file)

**Win32 Disk Imager** is a corresponding tool in Windows. See the following link,

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD)